# Qt GUI: what is the fastest way to load a binary pixmap?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a binary file called terrain.bil which has 54478160 items, and I would like to use information contained in this file to plot a 7988x6820 pixmap. And here is my code:

```
QFile op("terrain.bil");
op.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray rawArr = op.readAll();
const qint16 *rawData = (const qint16*) rawArr.data();
op.close();

QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap(7988,6820);
pixmap.fill(Qt::white);
QPainter pixPaint(&pixmap);
QPoint q1;
for(int i=0;i<6820;++i){
    for(int j=0;j<7988;++j){
        q1.setX(j);//QPixmap(#Col,#Row)
        q1.setY(i);
        if (rawData[i*7988+j] != -9999){
            pixPaint.setPen(QColor(floor(double(rawData[i*7988+j])*0.59),floor(double(rawData[i*7988+j])*0.59),floor(double(rawData[i*7988+j])*0.59),255));
        }
        else{
            pixPaint.setPen(Qt::green);
        }

        pixPaint.drawPoint(q1);
    }
}
scene->addPixmap(pixmap);
```

I tried to plot the pixmap point by point and it takes 1 minute to finish the double for loop. Is there any way that I can plot faster with this binary file?

Thanks very much!!!

Comment: wouldnt creating QImage and setings its pixel be faster than using qpainter on qpixmap? the approach is the same..

Comment: Is the performance bottleneck in the file reading or the drawing of the pixmap?

Comment: Since the input file is a 54478160x1 array, after I load the data I need to convert it to a 7988x6820 array first. This is the step which takes 1 minute. Read file and draw picture is really really fast and less than 1s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest writing a tool that will draw your pixmaps and serialize them as a binary file.
You can load the file directly into a pixmap and call a function to display the pixmap.

Also research "bit blitting".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QImage` to get direct access to the pixel data without using `QPainter` object.
That way you use `QImage::setPixel` with `qRgb` macro. Look [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#pixel-manipulation) to get more info on this. Then you can convert `QImage` to `QPixmap` and add it to your scene.

Comment: Hi, the input file is like a 54478160x1 array, is there any way that I can directly convert this array into a 7988x6820 image using QImage? Thanks